# URL access symfony 3.4

Tags: apache, url, multilingual, symfony-3.4

I have a site developed under symfony 3.4 and to access it I am obliged to put at the end of the url  a /fr (for French). For example : www.test.com/fr

Could someone tell me what I need to change and where, so that I do not have to type in my URL "/fr" at the end, but for redirection to be automatic

Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

Which web server hosts your site ? It is an apache web server ?

If it is an apache server you can try to change the document root of your site with 'fr' suffix.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.test.com
    ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site/web/fr

    <Directory "/var/www/site/web">
        DirectoryIndex app.php
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```